# how to put a whole output of a view into a element of a JSON object?

Tags: php, json, view

My task is to save replay of user once submited and update the view, where we can see latest replay.  for this i am using post method

```
$.post(url, dataString, function(data) {               
    if(data.error_message != '') $(".forum_replay").html(data.content); 
    // some thing
},"json");
```

In controller, i am saving data if there is no error.and then i want to update the view

```
$content = $this->load->view( $this->config->item('View_forum_replies') );
$json_data = array('error_message' => $message,
                   '$content'      => $content);
echo json_encode($json_data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an error right here:

```
'$content'      => $content
```

you need to drop the $ from the first portion

you might also want to change

```
if(data.error_message != '')
```

to

```
if(data.error_message == '')
```